# Enabling EnableIPv6 option for the docker Host network

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

When I start docker, it creates two networks (host and bridge). I need my host-bound Traefik instance to see the real external IPv6, but the EnableIPv6 option when doing `docker network inspect host` is set to false. I have IPv6 enabled in my daemon.json file, but it still reports the remote IP as `172.18.0.1`.

My traefik config file can be found at https://github.com/randomairborne/composed/blob/main/traefik.yml

and here is my docker daemon.json

```json
{
  "ipv6": true,
  "fixed-cidr-v6": "fd00::/64",
  "experimental": true, 
  "ip6tables": true 
}
```